# jQuery remove specific element from div that contains specific title

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs with the same class:

```
<div class="1">
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="1">
  <a href="#">Welcome</a>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
...
```

I need to remove all the divs which contain a link with a name  "Hello".
I only came up with this: `$(".1").remove(":contains('Hello')");` But it removes also the divs which contain Hello text in their p tags..

Answer (score 0):

Use `.has()` to filter out the elements which having anchor tag with `href` hello. Basically it will `filter` the element by checking whether the `source element` is having the `target element` which was passed as a `parameter`.

Try,

```
$('.1').has('a[href="Hello"]').remove()
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VB77v/1/)

You are having some invalid `markups` too, You just missed out the `closing angle brackets` at each `anchor` tag. Here is the valid version of your HTML,

```
<div class="1">
   <a href="Hello">hello</a>
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div id='test' class="1">
   <a href="Welcome">welcome</a>
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Based on your comment in Arun Bro's Post,

Try,

```
$('.1').has('a:contains("Hello")').remove()
```

### [DEMO - I](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/VB77v/2/)

Comment: Why should the OP try that? Why does it solve the problem? Please **explain** your solution, don't just post code.

Comment: @user3102636 Glad it worked for you. Consider this post as an accepted. :)